# Remove a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

When I want to remove a Cookie I try

```
unset($_COOKIE['hello']);
```

I see in my cookie browser from firefox that the cookie still exists. How can I really remove the cookie?

Comment: You may find `$cookie->delete()` from https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie helpful. The code from the question just deletes the property that has been parsed on the server-side. The cookie will still live on on the client side.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

You May Try this

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['remember_user']); 
    setcookie('remember_user', '', -1, '/'); 
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i use : if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user']) && !empty($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) { }

Comment: @machineaddict `unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);` is actually important if you might check the cookie somewhere later in the code.

Comment: @Andreas Hultgren: Well, it depends on how you code. You cannot have that problem. If you have deleted a cookie in the current session, you know it is deleted, what's the point of checking? For the next session it's pointless to `unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);` in the current session. And as session, I refer to a full pageload.

Comment: working fine but when try to reload page. it saw cookie set with old data why?.

Comment: =======DOES NOT WORK IN CHROME=======

I tried this code today and when I access the site using google chrome, and then go into developer tools in chrome, I can see that the expire time is set to 1 second before the epoch (e.g. 1969-12-31 23:59:59) however when I next submit the page the cookie is submitted to the server. When I changed the -1 to 1 (e.g. 1970-01-01 00:00:01) to give the following command:
     setcookie('Hello', null, 1, '/');
then chrome acted as expected and did not submit the cookie

Comment: I would definitely not use `-1` for the timestamp. Also, because of timezones, I would use a value of at least `86401` so that way you are in Jan 1970 whatever the locale. It should not be important, but for sure `-1` is not a good idea.

Comment: Along with @PeterHinds comment I just found that setting the value to NULL also throws an error, saying that setcookie() is expecting parameter 2 to be a string. So for anyone else finding this set the value to '' instead of null.

Comment: instead of -1 I would do something unsigned older than the current time. For me I find it best just to key in time()-10000 or just a small integer such as 1000

Comment: I got an error with null as second parameter:

setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/686166/1262663 should be the correct answer + unset($_COOKIE['hello'])

Comment: @OGM2 if you are using `declare(strict_types=1);` second parameter MUST be string. Seting null is depracated.

Comment: setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given

Comment: I don't see any issues saving a username inside a cookie

Comment: not working your solution

Answer (score 316):

Set the value to "" and the expiry date to yesterday (or any date in the past)

```
setcookie("hello", "", time()-3600);
```

Then the cookie will expire the next time the page loads.

Comment: How about setting the time to 0 (the epoch)?  =]

Comment: If you put a date too far in the past, IE will bark and igores it, i.e. the value will not be removed.

Comment: @strager The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) states: _If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)._

That's not really deleting the cookie.

I really don't know if IE will do what Julien said, but it's more than possible that IE will do something strange.

Comment: Also, don't forget to actually unset($_COOKIE["hello"]) too, because if there is code on the rest of the page that looks at $_COOKIE["hello"], it will still find it set.  I just got bit by this one.

Comment: Plus it's a good idea to set the path, so setcookie('hello', '', time()-3600, '/');

Comment: @Julien I can't find any reference to that which is not your comment. Which version of IE doesn't support this?

Comment: @Julien I tested this against IE6 and this does not seem to be the case. I set "expires" to 1 (1 second after the epoch) and IE6 seems to understand just fine that I want the cookie deleted -- on the next page load, the cookie is gone.

Comment: I found 1 reference to IE8: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-internetexplorer-general/357819-ie8-bug-cookie-expiration.html

Comment: It may not work when the client's time is not correct. I recommend `setcookie("hello", "", 1)` instead.

Comment: time()-3600 doesn't work if the user's system date is wrong and set, for example, to 2 days ago (or 2 hours)

Comment: `expiry date to yesterday` : you have set up 1 hr ago.

Comment: I've passed one hour trying to fix a non-working cookie replacement / unset ! This was due (I don't know why) to the path leaved blank...I replaced it by `'\'` like recommended by @StephanWeinhold and that worked fine..

Comment: in case the cookie's domain is not the default one then you have to pass the domain as fourth parameter of setcookie function too, as in general it's good to always set the third (path) and fourth (domain) parameters

Comment: @sepehr what about if the cookie was set with secure flag, and/or httponly flags? Do all the full combination of settings need to be exactly as they are to delete the cookie from the browser? Or can one easily get away with JUST path + domain?

Comment: instead of time()-3600 you should set 1 (1 second after unix epoq)

Answer (score 266):

A clean way to delete a cookie is to clear both of `$_COOKIE` value and browser cookie file :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['key']);
    setcookie('key', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // empty value and old timestamp
}
```

Comment: This is the best method, because you don't need to refresh page!

Comment: I keep going down the page and the answers keep getting better, funny. But this is the best one, stop looking here.

Comment: FYI, if you set the cookie using a path, you'll need to include the path in this `setcookie` call as well: `setcookie('key', '', time() - 3600, '/');`

Comment: @Gavin Thanks for that tip. I was wondering why it wasn't deleting, but was `unsetting` successfully.

Comment: For anyone that is checking a cookie's existence and cares about cookies that exist with `null` values, you'll need to use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/array_key_exists) instead, since a cookie with a `null` value won't get found by an `isset()` check.

Comment: I've found that if you set the cookie using a `$domain`, you also need to include the domain when clearing the cookie.

Comment: instead of time() - 3600 you should set 1 (1 second after unix epoc)

Comment: No more scrolling. Now, I stop my search for best answer here :)

Answer (score 38):

To reliably delete a cookie it's not enough to set it to expire anytime in the past, as computed by your PHP server. This is because client computers can and often do have times which differ from that of your server.

The best practice is to overwrite the current cookie with a blank cookie which expires one second after the epoch (1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC), as so:

```
setcookie('hello', '', 1);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but setting that to "1" would set it to a second after the epoch, not one second in the future..? I believe you're correct about time zone differences though, so the best solution would be to set it to 2 days in the past (so even the furthest away time zone would still unset the cookie).

Comment: @PaulSkinner the epoch date is independent of time zones, the computer does that computation for you.

Comment: @AlexR Yes. Doesn't really answer my point though. To my understanding, the code above *does* set the cookie to expire in the past (one second past the epoch), unless I am mistaken.

Comment: +1 for the "1". I don't understand why all others are so fixated on setting a deleted cookie exactly one hour in the past.

Answer (score 22):

That will unset the cookie in your code, but since the $_COOKIE variable is refreshed on each request, it'll just come back on the next page request.

To actually get rid of the cookie, set the expiration date in the past:

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("hello", "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: Isn't there any need to `unset()` the cookie ?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Only if your code looks for it later on.

Comment: instead of time()-3600 you should set 1 (1 second after unix epoq)

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem in my code and found that it was a cookie path issue.  Check out this stack overflow post: [Can't delete php set cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187132/cant-delete-php-set-cookie)

I had set the cookie using a path value of "/", but didn't have any path value when I tried to clear it, so it didn't clear.  So here is an example of what worked:

Setting the cookie:

```
$cookiePath = "/";
$cookieExpire = time()+(60*60*24);//one day -> seconds*minutes*hours
setcookie("CookieName",$cookieValue,$cookieExpire,$cookiePath);
```

Clearing the cookie:

```
setcookie("cookieName","", time()-3600, $cookiePath);
unset ($_COOKIE['cookieName']);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

If you set the cookie to expire in the past, the browser will remove it.  See [setcookie() delete example at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 8):

This is how PHP v7 setcookie() code works when you do:

```
<?php
    setcookie('user_id','');
    setcookie('session','');
?>
```

From the output of tcpdump while sniffing on the port 80, the server sends to the client (Browser) the following HTTP headers:

```
Set-Cookie: user_id=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0
Set-Cookie: session=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0
```

Observing packets in the following requests the Browser no longer sends these cookies in the headers

Answer (score 8):

Just set the value of cookie to `false` in order to unset it:

```
setcookie('cookiename', false);
```

Comment: This will throw Fatal Error if `declare(strict_types=1);` are defined.

Comment: This did not work at all, no errors, no warnings, no cookie deleted.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but in my little project: `setcookie('key', null);` seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

See the sample labelled "[Example #2 setcookie() delete example](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)" from the PHP docs. To clear a cookie from the browser, you need to tell the browser that the cookie has expired... the browser will then remove it. `unset` as you've used it just removes the 'hello' cookie from the COOKIE array.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete the cookie completely from all your current domain then the following code will definitely help you.

```
unset($_COOKIE['hello']);
setcookie("hello", "", time() - 300,"/");
```

This code will delete the cookie variable completely from all your domain i.e; " / " - it denotes that cookie variable's value all set for all domain not just for current domain or path. time() - 300 denotes that it sets to a previous time so it will expire.

Thats how it's perfectly deleted.

Answer (score 5):

To delete cookie you just need to set the value to NULL:

"If you've set a cookie with nondefault values for an expiration time, path, or domain, you must provide those same values again when you delete the cookie for the cookie to be deleted properly." 
Quote from "Learning PHP5" book.

So this code should work(works for me):

Setting the cookie:
`setcookie('foo', 'bar', time() + 60 * 5);`

Deleting the cookie:
`setcookie('foo', '', time() + 60 * 5);`

But i noticed that everybody is setting the expiry date to past, is that necessary, and why?

Comment: It is reliable, that's why. A combination of setting the value to nothing and a time in the past (but not too far as IE occasionally doesn't like it too far back from what I've read) works across the board.

Comment: The empty string `''` is not the same thing as `null`.

Answer (score 3):

I know that there has been a long time since this topic has been created but I saw a little mistake within this solution (I can call it like that, because it's a detail).
I agree that the better solution is probably this solution:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) {
            unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);
            unset($_COOKIE['HelloTest1']);
            setcookie('Hello', null, -1, '/');
            setcookie('HelloTest1', null, -1, '/');
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

But, in the present case, you delete the cookies in every case where the unset function works and immediately you create new expired cookies in case that the unset function doesn't work.

That means that even if the unset function works, it will still have 2 cookies on the computer.
The asked goal, in a logical point of view, is to delete the cookies if it is possible and if it really isn't, make it expire; to get "the cleanest" result.

So, I think we better should do:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) {
            setcookie('Hello', null, -1, '/');
            setcookie('HelloTest1', null, -1, '/');
            unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);
            unset($_COOKIE['HelloTest1']);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: Function unset is meant for PHP's logic (if you want to use the variable $_COOKIE['Hello'], you can't as it is unset). And the function setcookie is meant for the navigator. 2 different purposes, the order of the functions has no impact on the actual code.

Comment: In fact, I known it yep but if you absolutely want to be sure that the cookie has been unset/deleted and so you use the two solutions right up, it would be cleaner to before make theses expire and then unset theses than unset theses and then recreate an expired cookie... if you see what I mean?

Comment: Yep, sorry replying just now :) I've sent it because I had seen people doing it in the other way.. but it seems more clever like that, i think.

Comment: Cookie value must be string. In this case, a empty string: `''`. Maybe `null` generates a warning... See [PHP: setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 2):

To remove all cookies you could write:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
    unset($value);
    setcookie($key, '', time() - 3600);
}
```

Comment: This will not actually remove the cookies unless they have the same path and domain settings as the defaults to setcookie.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the expiration date to one hour ago, if you want to "remove" the cookie, like this:

```
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
```

or

```
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You should use the `filter_input()` function for all globals which a visitor can enter/manipulate, like this:

```
$visitors_ip = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'id');
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php and here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input.asp

Comment: instead of time() - 3600 you should set 1 (1 second after unix epoc)

Answer (score 2):

```
$cookie_name = "my cookie";
$cookie_value = "my value";
$cookie_new_value = "my new value";

// Create a cookie,
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value , time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); //86400 = 24 hours in seconds

// Get value in a cookie,
$cookie_value = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

// Update a cookie,
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_new_value , time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

// Delete a cookie,
setcookie($cookie_name, '' , time() - 3600, "/"); //  time() - 3600 means, set the cookie expiration date to the past hour.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple!

```
setcookie("cookiename", "cookievalue", 1);
```

Comment: It's not needed to set value for a deleting cookie!

Comment: @AmirFo, it _is_ necessary, even if the value is an empty string. Doesn't really matter what the example string is here.

Answer (score 2):

I found that in Chrome it's impossible to unset a cookie unless you define the last three parameters in the cookie... The domain, that it's secure and http only...

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
unset($_COOKIE['user_id']); 
setcookie("user_id", "", time() - 3600, "/", 'yourdomain.com',true,true);
header('Location: /');
} else {
/* other code here */
}
```

This is how I made it work for me.
Read the documentation: [All about cookies in the official PHP Site](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: PHP 7.1+: `Can't use temporary expression in write context`

Answer (score 1):

You could set a session variable based on cookie values

```
session_start();

if(isset($_COOKIE['loggedin']) && ($_COOKIE['loggedin'] == "true") ){
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
}

echo ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == "true" ? "You are logged in" : "Please Login to continue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this customize function:

```
function unset_cookie($cookie_name) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        setcookie($cookie_name, null, -1);
    } else { return false; }
}
```

If you want to remove $_COOKIE['user_account'].
Just use:

```
unset_cookie('user_account');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `0` for time, you mean **"now"** (+0s from now is actually now) for the browser and it deletes the cookie.

```
setcookie("key", NULL, 0, "/");
```

I checked it in chrome browser that gives me:

```
Name: key
Content: Deleted
Created: Sunday, November 18, 2018 at 2:33:14 PM
Expires: Sunday, November 18, 2018 at 2:33:14 PM
```

Comment: No. Just read the docs. "If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)."

Comment: @DrLightman Thank you for your attendance, Can you please cite the documentation?

Comment: [function.setcookie.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), **expires** parameter. "If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)."

Answer (score 0):

I,m used this in **php** and it **worked** fine.

```
function cookie_unset()
{
    setcookie("cookie_name", "", time() - 3600, '/');
    unset ($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
    //done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unset` or `setcookie`

```
unset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']);
//
setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/');
```

I prefer to check with `isset` and than `unset or setcookie`

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE'])) { unset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']); }
//
if(isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE'])) { setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/'); }
```

this seems to work too, but don't use it in my opinion

```
setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/') ?? '';
```

```
!isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']) ?: setcookie('MYCOOKIE', '', -1, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('key', '', time() - 3600, '/')
```

may not work if client's time is wrong. More straightforward to use:

```
setcookie('key', '', 1, '/');
```

Reference: User contribution notes at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score -2):

You have to delete cookies with php in your server and also with js for your browser.. (They has made with php, but cookie files are in the browser client too):

An example:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'exit'){
            // delete cookies with js and then in server with php:
            echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var delete_cookie = function(name) {
                     document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
                };
                delete_cookie("madw");
                delete_cookie("usdw");
            </script>
            ';
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_time']);
```

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to set/delete the cookie value. The php function setcookie will do that for you http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score -5):

Most of you are forgetting that this will only work on a local machine.
On a domain you will need a pattern like this example.

```
setcookie("example_cookie", 'password', time()-3600, "/", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Comment: The domain parameter will mean the current domain if it is omitted.

Comment: I meant to say that your answer is incorrect. It will work for any domain, not just the local machine, as it will automatically use the current domain.

And your comment means to say you are offended or something?

Comment: I don't understand why you're getting annoyed at other users if they're pointing out a mistake in your answer. `setcookie` works for any domain, whether localhost or not.