# Can't delete php set cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I've set a cookie through this call in php

```
setcookie('alert_msg', 'you have the add badge');
```

I have tried unsetting it this way

```
setcookie('alert_msg', '');
setcookie('alert_msg', false);
setcookie('alert_msg', false, 1);
setcookie('alert_msg', false, time()-3600);
setcookie('alert_msg', '', 1, '/');
```

and it still won't unset the cookie value in $_COOKIE['alert_msg'].

I have tried in both Firefox and Chrome

Code sample:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['alert_msg'])) {
    $this->set('alert_msg', $_COOKIE['alert_msg']);
    unset($_COOKIE['alert_msg']);
    setcookie('alert_msg', '', 1, '/');
}
```

Comment: Checkout the cookie path. Are you setting cookie in `dir/file` and trying to unset in `dir2/file`?

Comment: @Shakti - I'm using Cakephp. I'm setting it in one controller which sits in /app/controllers and trying to unset it in the app_controller which is sitting in /app does this make a difference?

Comment: @Shakti - I see you are correct, can you please add your comment as an answer and I can mark it as my accepted answer.

Comment: dots in cookie names are replaced by _ chars - this might cause some problems

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->delete()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L173) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Checkout the cookie path.

Since you are not passing the `path` parameter to the `setcookie` function, in this case the cookie will be set for the current directory only and can be used and can be unset from that directory only.

Possible solution is to pass the `path` value as `/`. So that cookie can be used and unset from any part of application.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is having issues with this: in my particular case I was unable to delete a cookie because it was set in the https version of the site and I was visiting the http version.
Always redirect to https!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, as per your app design you have to set some cookie details ( for example the path to be something other than / ). Deleting the cookie RELIABLY only works if you can identify that cookie clearly ( everything that you set in it ) for deletion.

Use the code below for reliable deletion;

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();              // extract cookie details
unset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] );                  // unset the cookie
setcookie(session_name(), " " , 1 , 
          $params["path"], $params["domain"], 
          $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] ); // and also expire the cookie
```

Note1: Set time to expire to 1 sec past unix epoch time. No need to worry that the user's machine  has time correctly set.

Note2: setcookie takes max 7 parameters, so we leave out $params["lifetime"].
The other params are the main ones.