# How to delete/unset a cookie on php?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, session-timeout

I want to unset/delete my existing cookie with this:

```
setcookie ("user", "", time()-1); 
unset($user);
```

But cookies can not be deleted or unset. So what is problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: // MUST provide root path or any particular cookie path 

//SET COOKIE
setcookie ("user", "", time() + 3600 , '/'); 

//UNSET COOKIE
setcookie ("user", "", time()-100 , '/' ); // past time

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->delete()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L173) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can unset cookies this way only may -1 not work

try this

```
setcookie ("user", "", time() - 3600);
```

Comment: I did as you said but got nothing

Comment: does you change "user" with your cookie name and if so than may some other problem but in php we can unset cookie this way only...

Answer (score 4):

When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past.

Delete example:

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("user", "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: I did as you said but got nothing

Answer (score 3):

Nothing - that code looks fine to me.

Quoting the docs:

> When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser.

```
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
```

You may like to specify a time that's more in the past to avoid problems with the computer's time that may be a bit off.

Additionally, in some cases it's useful to actually unset `$_COOKIE['TestCookie']` as well.

Answer (score 3):

As already was said - when deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past.

BUT you also have to **use the same path and even domain**  for deleting, which you used for cookie creating, so if create cookie like this

```
setcookie ("user", "John", time()+7200, '/', 'mydomain.com');
```

to delete this cookie use this code

```
setcookie ("user", "", time()-3600, '/', 'mydomain.com');
```

and also better use specific date in the past instead of *time() - 3600*

Answer (score 3):

// **MUST provide root path or any particular cookie path**

```
//SET COOKIE
setcookie ("user", "", time() + 3600 , '/'); 

//UNSET COOKIE
setcookie ("user", "", time()-100 , '/' ); // past time
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setcookie ("user", "", time() - 3600);
//will reset cookie(client,browser)
unset($_COOKIE["user"]);
// will destroy cookie(server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing on this page is correct except the code where the cookie path is included. The cookies are not removed unless a path is specified.