# My cookie does not want to delete itself

Tags: php, cookies

I want to delete a cookie and it does not work.

Here is the code, any ideas?

```
    setcookie("candidate_site_search", serialize($model->getAttributes()), strtotime('next year'), '/');

    if (isset($_GET['clearFilters']) && ($_GET['clearFilters'] == 1)) {
        //die('cf');
        $model->unsetAttributes();
        setcookie("candidate_site_search", serialize($model->getAttributes()), time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        if (isset($_COOKIE['candidate_site_search']))
            unset($_COOKIE['candidate_site_search']);
        if (isset($_COOKIE['site_search']))
            unset($_COOKIE['site_search']);
        $this->redirect(array('/candidate/search'));
    }
```

After delete, i redirect to the same url from where the request came.

still nothing happens

p.s: I think this cookie is related to Chuck Norris, or at least Superman ...

Comment: Does that `if` evaluate true?

Comment: Delete the cookie using the same optional arguments as when you set the cookie. Like path, domain, etc..

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: that';s the example that i followed, does not work

Comment: Ehm.. According to PHP.net you're doing it right. Are you sure the script is being executed? If you un-comment your die('cf'); does it die with the messages "cf" ?

Comment: yes, it dies with cf comment

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the `redirect` that is faulty?

Comment: I know this might sound stupid, but im all out of ideas here. The page you redirect to doesnt set the cookie again, does it? :P Try not redirecting it and just use die(); right after the setcookie.

Comment: ok, so there are also some $_COOKIE variables that i need to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the date/time you have set on your server in relation to the time on the client.

For instance if your server is GMT+2 and your client is GMT, then the code above will tell the client to expire the cookie at GMT+1 which is still in the future for the client.

Just use a time that is waaay back in the past so you eliminate any time zone issues:

```
setcookie("name_of_cookie", "", time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30); // should  do it
```

Comment: Why not just `setcookie("name_of_cookie", "", 1);`?

Comment: IE will bark and ignore this.