# trying to delete cookies - headers already sent error

Tags: php, session, cookies, http-headers

i got headers already sent error. I know what that error means but i cant solve it.. This is my admin login/logout system..

**index.php**

```
    <?php
    if(empty($_COOKIE['user'])){
    include '/views/admin/login.php';
    }
    elseif(isset($_COOKIE['user']) || isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    include '/views/admin/admin.php';
    }
    ?>
```

**login.php**

```
    <?php include('/views/admin/header-login.php') ;?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="full_w">
                    <form method="post">
                    <h3 id="logins-error"></h3>
                        <label for="login">Username:</label>
                        <input id="login" name="login" class="text" />
                        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="text" />
                        <div class="sep"></div>
                        <button class="login-button" class="ok">Login</button> <a class="button" href="">Forgotten password?</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">&raquo; <a href="/">Avetisyan</a> | Admin Panel</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('/views/admin/footer.php'); ?>
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php include('/views/admin/header.php') ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="top">
            <div class="left">
                <p>Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?></strong> [ <a href="/admin/logout">logout</a> ]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="align-right">
                    <p>Avetisyan | Admin Panel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/main">Main</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/about-us">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/for-teachers">For Teachers</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/for-pupils">For pupils</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/graduates">Graduates</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/news">News</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/kindergarten">Kindergarten</a></li>
                <li class="upp"><a href="/admin/materials">Materials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="h_title">&#8250; Pages</div>
            <ul id="home">
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/main">Main</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/about-us">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/for-teachers">For Teachers</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/for-pupils">For Pupils</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/graduates">Graduates</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/news">News</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/kindergarten">Kindergarten</a></li>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="/admin/materials">Materials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    <div class="full_w">
        <div class="h_title">Paragraph, headers, lists, notify</div>
        <h1>Level 1 header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diamvoluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takim</p>
        <h2>Level 2 header</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diamvoluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor i</p>
        <h3>Level 3 header</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diamvolupt</p>
        <h3>Unordered list</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>first list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>second list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>third list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>fourth list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Ordered list</h3>
        <ol>
            <li>first list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>second list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>third list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
            <li>fourth list item, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consete</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="n_warning"><p>Attention notification. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor.</p></div>
        <div class="n_ok"><p>Success notification. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor.</p></div>
        <div class="n_error"><p>Error notification. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor.</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="full_w">
        <div class="h_title">Add new page - form elements</div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="element">
                <label for="name">Page title <span class="red">(required)</span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" class="text err" />
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <label for="category">Category <span class="red">(required)</span></label>
                <select name="category" class="err">
                    <option value="0">-- select category</option>
                    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Category 4</option>
                    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                <input type="radio" name="comments" value="on" checked="checked" /> Enabled <input type="radio" name="comments" value="off" /> Disabled
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <label for="attach">Attachments</label>
                <input type="file" name="attach" />
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <label for="content">Page content <span>(required)</span></label>
                <textarea name="content" class="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <button type="submit">Preview</button> <button type="submit" class="add">Save page</button> <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="full_w">
        <div class="h_title">Manage pages - table</div>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumyeirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diamvolupt</p>

        <div class="entry">
            <div class="sep"></div>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Author</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">2</td>
                <td>Home</td>
                <td>Paweł B.</td>
                <td>22-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">3</td>
                <td>Our offer</td>
                <td>Paweł B.</td>
                <td>22-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">5</td>
                <td>About</td>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td>23-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">12</td>
                <td>Contact</td>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td>25-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">114</td>
                <td>Portfolio</td>
                <td>Paweł B.</td>
                <td>22-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">116</td>
                <td>Clients</td>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td>23-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="align-center">131</td>
                <td>Customer reviews</td>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td>25-03-2012</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon archive" title="Archive"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="pagination">
                <span>« First</span>
                <span class="active">1</span>
                <a href="">2</a>
                <a href="">3</a>
                <a href="">4</a>
                <span>...</span>
                <a href="">23</a>
                <a href="">24</a>
                <a href="">Last »</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <a class="button add" href="">Add new page</a> <a class="button" href="">Categories</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="left">
            <p><a href="http://webex.am">Webex Technologies LLC</a> | Admin Panel: <a href="/">Avetisyan</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php include('/views/admin/footer.php') ?>
```

When the user fill the fields and submit, it goes to validate.php

**validate.php**

```
<?php
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password']));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE name =  '$user' AND pass =  '$password' AND privileges = 'superuser'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($num_rows == '0') {
    echo "error";
}
else if($num_rows == '1') {
$expire = time()+3600;
setcookie("user","$user",$expire);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
include '/views/admin/admin.php';
}
```

Now when he is logged in, it include admin.php and in admin.php is link to logout, it goes to logout.php

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_destroy();
$expire = time()-4000;
setcookie("user","$user",$expire);
?>
```

And here it say

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\logout.php:1) in
>   Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\logout.php on line 4

Please give me the solution, the fixed code so i can continue my work :)

Thanks!!

EDIT

**header.php**

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nor-Avetisyan Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL ?>views/admin/css/navi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL ?>views/admin/css/style.css">
<script src="<?php echo URL ?>views/js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should follow those instruction :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php 
[Remove a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Try calling session_destroy() after a setcookie().

```
<?php
session_start();
$expire = time()-4000;    
setcookie("user","",$expire);
session_destroy();
?>
```

A+
LAL

Comment: Still nothing. There still appear an error, and cookie dont delete.

Comment: omg... i aleady seen this.. Please just look at the code and tell me which part is the problem

Comment: What's telling you it is not expired ? It's still in your browser data ? Or you still have acces to values via PHP ?

Comment: cause i can see it in cookies list via google chrome, and if its expired, it would show login.php

Comment: Have you tried to unset the value of you cookie ?
setcookie("user", "", time()-3600);



Otherwise, i don't know.

Comment: are you even looking my post? i wrote whole code! there is setcookie with -time!

Comment: Yes, and i don't like you attitude. I'm trying to help you.
there a difference between your code: setcookie("user","$user", time()-3600) and my code setcookie("user","", time()-3600) on the second parameter.

Comment: Ok, then it should already work. But i think you are missing a session_start() in your index.php

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\logout.php:1) in
>   Z:\home\test1.ru\www\views\admin\logout.php on line 4

It says exactly where the output started.

NO .. OUTPUT .. BEFORE .. HEADER()

(or functions that send headers, like setcookie, session_Start, etc)

Comment: the first line in logout.php is <?php, i already pasted all code!

Comment: There are alot of includes, that why im asking where is the problem

Comment: @Tigran Muradyan: no output before the `admin.php` and in `admin.php`

Comment: EL - not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean to remove any output before `admin.php` inclusion and make sure that `setcookie()` in `admin.php` doesnt have output above.

Comment: when using utf-8 as file encoding, be sure NOT to use the BOM (byte order mark)! This is sometimes hard to find, as most editors won't show the BOM (use a HEX editor to find out)