# How to properly "delete" a Cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have created a PHP and Cookie-based Login and Logout system for the admin page of a WebApp I am working on. Issue is when I refresh the page more than 2 or 3 times when I am Logged In, the Log Out function doesn't work properly, and keeps me "Logged In" if I attempt to load an admin page after I have "Logged Out". I am not certain if this is a browser setting, or something I am coding incorrectly.

Login PHP Code:

`setcookie("password","$thepassword");`

Logout PHP Code:

> unset($_COOKIE['password']);
>
> setcookie('password', null, -1, '/');

Any ideas welcome. :) Thanks~

Comment: should you really be storing the users password as a cookie?

Comment: you should store user details in session not cookies!

Comment: @dbh I am, I just modded the code so you guys wouldn't be confused. I am transferring the data from the database to variables, so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @AlbertKozłowski I'm open minded, why do you think a session would be more beneficial?

Comment: @UncleNerdicus Okay just checking, I'm with ALbert on this one though.

Answer (score 4):

A few seconds of [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=delete%20cookie%20php) search would save you the hassle of asking a question, thought its already been answered here before, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

I would also mention that storing users passwords in a cookie is a crime! please use sessions for such an ocassion.

Comment: Actually, I am using the EXACT same code from that article in my case. I LOOKED at that same article writing the present code. lol!

Answer (score 1):

You can always assign the cookie a null value:

```
setcookie("user", NULL);
```

However, cookies tend to be a rather insecure way of storing user data. I strongly recommend using sessions in stead. Keep in mind that users can change the value of cookies, but not sessions. Then to log out you can use session_destroy()

Also, try refreshing the page after the cookie is unset.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues by converting the script to use Sessions, and not Cookies.

Thanks for the advice guys. :)