# Why won't my cookie delete?

Tags: php

I have a cookie, that I set with the following command:

```
setcookie( 'auth', 'cookie data' , time() + 3600, '/', '.mydomain.com', true, true );
```

when I log out, I call a function to clear it, which does this:

```
setcookie( 'auth', "", time() - 3600, '/', '.mydomain.com', true, true );
```

However, if I then refresh the page, $_COOKIE['auth'] is still set, and returns the old 'cookie data' value that should be gone!

What am I missing?

Comment: is the time of the server or the client off ? They should be the same time

Comment: You should probably choose a lower value than `time() - 3600`, since that might not work if the end-user lives in a different time zone. How about `1` instead?

Comment: Check your HTTP traffic. That should tell you the issue.

Comment: hi, try with mktime();

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: @WaleedKhan the time zone shouldnt matter. But the use of `1` should work

Comment: Though [it is said elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie#comment501666_686166) that IE might ignore the cookie request if it's too far in the past.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - even `time() - 42000` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($_COOKIE['auth']);  
setcookie('auth', '');
```

Comment: although I hate code-dumps too, unsetting the `$_COOKIE['auth']` global before doing the set in the past took care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you haven't already sent headers
   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php
2. make sure you are sending headers. Are you outputting anything else? If not, echo anything to make sure headers are sent before exit.
3. remove from cookie global array also

   if(isset($_COOKIE['auth'])) {
     unset($_COOKIE['auth']);
   }
4. if your session name is 'auth', any change to session data may rewrite the session cookie

Comment: headers have not been sent at that point, but are sent before the script terminates

Comment: try removing from cookie globals also, you haven't by any chance called your session 'auth'? because that might do it also if you change session data after deleting cookie