# PHP filter_input returns deleted cookie

Tags: php, cookies, filter-input

as far as I could figure out (e.g. [Remove a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)) the typical procedure to delete a cookie in PHP is:

- use "setcookie" to set an expiration in the past so the browser will delete the cookie upon next page reload.
- call "unset" to remove the cookie from the "$_COOKIE" superglobal.

But when I now try to access the cookie using "filter_input" it is still set. It seems to me that "filter_input" does not access the "$_COOKIE" superglobal but uses some other internal buffer.

Is there a way I can delete the cookie once and forever so that even "filter_input" won't return it any more?

Thanks for your help

Here's my example code:

```
<?php

// assembles the current URL
function currentUrl() {

    $https = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTPS', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $protocol = $https ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $serverName = filter_input(
            INPUT_SERVER, 'SERVER_NAME', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $port = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])
            ? ':' . filter_input(
                    INPUT_SERVER, 'SERVER_PORT', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
            : '';
    $requestURI = filter_input(
            INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    $pageURL = $protocol . $serverName . $port . $requestURI;
    return $pageURL;
}


const COOKIE_NAME = 'foo';
const COOKIE_VALUE = 'bar';

// ensure that we have our cookie set
$cookie = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, COOKIE_NAME, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
if (empty($cookie)) {
    $expires = time() + 60*60;
    setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, COOKIE_VALUE, $expires);
    header('Location: ' . currentUrl());
    die();
}

// remove the cookie from $_COOKIE
unset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME]);
print_r($_COOKIE);      // this won't list our cookie
echo '<br/>';

$cookie = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, COOKIE_NAME, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
echo $cookie;           // this will print the cookie content
```

Comment: `filter_input` does indeed not use the `$_COOKIE` array, but an internal hash. And unsetting a cookie per `setcookie` will first take effect with the following HTTP request.

Comment: I could use a workaround of course: filter_var($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);