# Setting / deleting cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am facing a strange issue while setting and deleting cookies.

I am setting a cookie with the line below:

```
setcookie( $cookie, base64_encode( $step . $val ), time() + 3600, '/', 'domain.com' );
```

The cookie is set correctly with the given expiration time.

Trying to delete it with the following line:

```
setcookie( $cookie, '', time() - 3600, '/', 'domain.com' );
```

This does not remove the cookie, rather firebug shows this as a session cookie now!!

Can you please let me know what i might be doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use relative times for deleting a cookie. Just set time `1`, since you have no idea whether the user's system is actually "in sync" with real time. e.g. their clock could be 2 hours slow, in which case you're setting an expiry time one hour in THEIR future.

Comment: actually, i am using `date_default_timezone_set` for setting and deleting the cookies