# Session cookie not deleting

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm using cookies on my site without expiration dates defined so they expire on the browser close but I'm having issues unsetting them. I'm using the following code to unset them but it's not correctly doing it. I should also add that I want it to remove it from all pages on the site. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Code used to unset cookie

```
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['dash']);
}
```

Cookie is being set like this:

```
setcookie("dash", $row['ID'], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: and its not a "session cookie"

Comment: I tried what you said and it gives me the following error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

Comment: so dont send any headers first

Comment: @Dagon What does it mean exactly by that error? I've been wondering this for a long time and have never really found an answer.

Comment: one of the most asked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: You set the cookie to expire within 10 years?

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes that was my intention for it to never expire, well almost never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the function to the top of the page before any output was sent, this fixed it.