# How can I delate cookie correctly?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['fastblade'])){
echo("Not set");

}else{
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    setcookie("fastblade", "", time() - 3600);

}
```

And the function to create cookie is:

```
function cookieGetURL(){
$cookie_name = 'fastblade';
$cookie_value = 'gen';
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

I don't know why I cant delete this cookie... 
I also tried

```
unset($_COOKIE['fastblade']);
```

Can anybody explain to me what Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19972329/980615

Comment: @kingkero I have been beaten by 1 second!

Comment: Actually - it ain't gonna work in this instance because of that `print_r()` before the `setcookie()` - you've got to set your cookies (or unset them) before outputting anything - they're part of the HTTP header.

Comment: It doesn't help at all