# Delete cookie with php when user login

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem. So I create a cookie when user is not connected and tried to access an image. And I want to delete this cookie when user login to application.
I created like this :

```
setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $generatedToken, time() + self::COOKIE_LIFETIME_DAY * 86400, self::COOKIE_PATH, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

And the cookie is correct created, but when I tried to delete the cookie doesn't work.I tried like this :

```
setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, '', 1);
```

And like this :

```
unset($_COOKIE[self::COOKIE_NAME]);
setcookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, '', time() - 30);
```

And the same situation. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you sure your code is reaching that point? Put an `echo` just above the point to see if it's output on the page. And why have you tagged this question with two version of PHP? Deleting your tags, add back in *one* version.

Comment: The code reaching that point..

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie

Comment: "Then the cookie will expire the next time the page loads." the next time the page loads, so what you do is unset the cookie and then recall / reload the page.