# I can't delete cookies PHP although path and time was set correctly

Tags: php, cookies

I have created a logout.php page to let the user sign out from the website and redirects them to the sign in page.

however what ever i do, the cookies are not getting deleted, so when the user gets redirected to the singin page the latter examines the cookies and then find it, therefore logs the user in.

Below is the code of logout.php:

```
<?php
unset($login);
if (isset($_COOKIE['xxx'])){
    setcookie('xxx', false, time() - 3600,"/");
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['yyy'])){
    setcookie('yyy', false, time() - 3600,"/");
}
    header("Location: singin.php");
    die();

?>
```

Please note that this php page is in subfolder protected by password and the html link redirects to a php file that require() the logout.php file.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie
Let us know if it helped

Comment: `if (isset($_COOKIE['X'])){
    setcookie('X'` - Do you know what that does? Think about it for a minute and tell yourself *out loud*, step by step.

Comment: *"How did you set the cookies in the first place?"* @PetervanderWal Oh, it's set alright. Look at their code again ;-) Edit: I see you deleted the comment I was responding to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I had to read your comment twice before I saw the problem, but of course you're abslolutely right ;)

Comment: @PetervanderWal ;-)

Comment: @PetervanderWal Thing is though Peter, you wrote something else in your (deleted) comment that made sense, being domain-related. If you remember what you wrote, you should add that as (another) comment.

Comment: Although this isn't your current problem (at least not your main probem, @Fred-ii- is nudging you in the right direction): You should make sure that you delete your cookie with the same parameters for `$path`, `$domain` and `$secure` as you set it in the first place. For example if you set a cookie with `$domain = '.example.com'` (i.e. example.com itself and all subdomains under it), you can't delete it with `$domain = 'www.example.com'` or leaving the `$domain`-parameter out.

Comment: I have set the cookies as follows: 'setcookie('xxx' , value, 3600*24, "/")'

Comment: @PetervanderWal the code now is as the following:<?php
unset($login);

 unset($_COOKIE['xxx']);
 setcookie('xxx', null, -1,'/');

 

 unset($_COOKIE['yyy']);
 setcookie('yyy', null, -1,'/');
 
 header("Location: signin.php");
 die();
}
?>

Comment: and still doesn't work

Comment: is it possible that this problem related to session_cache_limiter for some reason?, I'm trying to think out of the box, because i can see the cookie in the firefox alive, on more thing, sometimes it works for one time, when I login to the account again it stucks and the cookie is never been deleted, last thing, If i delete the cookie manually from Firefox nothing creates it again in the website and the user remain logged out.

Comment: `setcookie('xxx', $value, 3600*24, "/")` WON'T set a cookie since the timestamp `3600*24` would be somewhere Jan 2nd 1970. So if you had a cookie, you did create it another way. Make it `setcookie('xxx', $value, time() + 3600*24, "/")`. Then (at least in my environment) `setcookie('xxx', null, -1, "/")` WILL delete that same cookie.

Answer (score 0):

use php `unset()` to delete your cookie as, you can get the complete details here [delete the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['xxx'])){
    unset($_COOKIE['xxx']);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['yyy'])){
    unset($_COOKIE['yyy']);
}
```

or, set value as `null` and a negative time for your cookie as

```
setcookie('xxx', null, -1, '/');
setcookie('yyy', null, -1, '/');
```

or, set value as `empty` and a past time for your cookie as

```
setcookie("xxx", "", time()-3600);
setcookie("yyy", "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: I have tried both of them, it doesn't work the cookie still alive!.

Comment: hardly refresh `CTRL + F5` your page, and then check

Comment: I've forced the refresh, same problem, the cookie actually can be seen in firefox cookies

Comment: sometimes after deleting the cookies, browser still display the cookies, you can test your code `unset($_COOKIE['xxx']);if (isset($_COOKIE['xxx'])){die("cookie exist");}else{die("cookie deleted");}`

Answer (score 0):

I have found finally the reason behind the issue.
it's because I have put `session_cache_limiter('public');` in my code, so which I presume prevents the client to set the cookie to an expiry date.

I have done that because I don't want the client to ask the user each time they hit back to resubmit the form.

It seems that it's not the correct practice, I'll post another question for that.

Thanks all for the help.