# Can I use strtotime to delete cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli, logout, strtotime

Can I use strtotime for deleting cookies?

```
setcookie("user", $row['email'],strtotime('+30 days'));
```

as per my logout.php, i used

```
setcookie("user", $row['email'], strtotime('-30 days'));
```

is this possible?

Comment: This link will help you to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie

Comment: Why -30 days? Isn't "now" enough?

Comment: If you want to delete the cookies, you just need to set expire time to something which is passed. even 1 second is also fine! no need to set it to -30 days. It will simply overwrite the expire time. I hope it will clear your concept to delete cookies!