# PHP Cookies Show Login Account List Gmail Like

Tags: php, cookies

I would like to implement multiple user login show like gmail login. See below image:

[image]

Current I'm using `COOKIE` to get the USERID. But it only give me the last USERID. not all.

Here is PHP to set COOKIE:

```
setcookie("cookielogin[userLoginRemembered]", $dataLoginQuery['USERID'] , $time + (60*60*24*7));
```

What I want is, to show all user ever logged in and display it using COOKIE.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you only set the cookie with with the current userid then it can't get all. You have to append the cookie to list them all.

Comment: Hi @Andreas how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only store last logged user id into cookie, and it overrides old value

Cookie only stores raw text, so if you want to store a list (array), you have to serialize it (by your own way or using serialize() function). This 
sample code below uses PHP's serialize():

```
$lastLoggedUserId = '123';
if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_key_for_logged_users'])) {
    $cookieLoggedUserIds = [$lastLoggedUserId];
} else {
// unserialize
    $cookieLoggedUserIds = (array) unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_key_for_logged_users']);
    $cookieLoggedUserIds[] = $lastLoggedUserId;
}
// just to make sure no duplicated user id to be stored
$cookieLoggedUserIds = array_unique($cookieLoggedUserIds);
setcookie('cookie_key_for_logged_users', serialize($cookieLoggedUserIds));
print_r(unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_key_for_logged_users']));
```

I've not tested this code, but it's easy to test and tweak.

Comment: Hi @Tuan How to display the output?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave: You can get all user IDs from cookie, then query to database to get more information: $cookieLoggedUserIds = (array) unserialize($_COOKIE['cookie_key_for_logged_users']); Or you can tweak the code to store more information to the cookie (like email/image,...)

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I've updated the code, you can run and see the output

Comment: Question, how to remove specific cookie?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave: You can simply set the cookie with expiration time in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie

Comment: I'm using this: setcookie("cookie_key_for_logged_users", "123", time()-3600); but it remove all the cookies.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave This code works for me: setcookie('cookie_key_for_logged_users', null, -1);

Comment: Hi @Tuan, I just want to remove specific cookies not all. Example I only want to remove user: 123. How to do that?

Comment: Hi @HiDayurieDave. You may look into how to remove one element in array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array. array_splice is your need. Then you remove "123" from the $cookieLoggedUserIds then setcookie again with new $cookieLoggedUserIds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154641/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-tuan-duong).

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the information in the cookie.
There is no append for cookies so what we need to do is read it's current value, add current string and write a new cookie.

```
$currentvalue = $_COOKIE["cookielogin[userLoginRemembered]"];
If(strpos($currentvalue, $dataLoginQuery['USERID']) !== false){
    Echo "username exist in cookie already";
}else{
    setcookie("cookielogin[userLoginRemembered]", $currentvalue .",". $dataLoginQuery['USERID'] , $time + (60*60*24*7));
//Here I set the value of cookie as current value and dataloginquery.
}
```

Output:

```
Var_dump(explode(",", $_COOKIE["cookielogin[userLoginRemembered]"]));
// Dumps the array of usernames that is comma separated.
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas, how to display the output?

Comment: @HiDayurie not sure what you mean. You need to echo them. I updated my post with how to access the array of user IDs.

Comment: That means you have not set your cookie. You need to set the cookie before trying to output it

Comment: I do, I'm using your code: setcookie("cookielogin[userLoginRemembered]", $currentvalue .",". $dataLoginQuery['USERID'] , $time + (60*60*24*7));

Comment: I don't know what code you use. Cookies are not just "set" read the manual about them. There is too much missing for me to know what you have done wrong. Have you looked if the browser saved the cookie?