# Can I include something in website that will make browsers delete cookies and forgot previous version?

Tags: javascript, php, web-deployment

Because any time I update website old website stays until I delete cookies. And I don't think every user will know how to delete cookies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie)

Comment: A website doesn't not update because of cookies; unless your server is doing something really weird and shows old content based on old cookies (?!). No, you probably have a general caching problem, and while deleting cookies you're also deleting the cached site. You need to think about your caching strategy and set cache headers appropriately. http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

[PHP setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484)

Taken from that page, this will unset all of the cookies for your domain:

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I delete cookies using this JS "deleteCookie(sName)":

```
function miTrim(cadena){
    var seguir;
    seguir = true;
    while ( cadena != "" && seguir) {
        if ( cadena.charAt(0)==' ' ) {
            cadena = cadena.substring(1, cadena.length );
        } else {
            if( cadena.charAt(cadena.length-1) == ' ') {
                cadena = cadena.substring(0, cadena.length-1 );
            } else {
                seguir = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return cadena;
}

function obtenerCookie( cookieBuscada ){
    var todasCookies = document.cookie;
    var matrizCookies = todasCookies.split(';');
    var unaCookie;
    var nombreCookie;
    var posicion;
    for ( var i= 0; i < matrizCookies.length; i++) {
        unaCookie = matrizCookies[i];
        posicion = unaCookie.indexOf("=")
        if ( posicion > 0) {
            nombreCookie = miTrim(unaCookie.substring(0,posicion));
        if (nombreCookie == cookieBuscada) {
            return unaCookie.substring(posicion +1);
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}


function deleteCookie(sName) {
    document.cookie = sName + "=" + obtenerCookie(sName) + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 1990 23:59:59 GMT;path=;";
}
```

Comment: Javascript is not the best solution to this problem because in certain cases some cookies are not reachable from javascript (and thus won't be affected by any JS code)